# How to implement a XAML Radio Button control with an ObservableCollection source?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, radio-button

I have the following **ComboBox** element in XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionControlValues}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CollectionControlSelectedValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I would like to implement **RadioButtons** in the **same way**, like this:

*PSEUDO-CODE:*

```
<RadioButtons ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionControlValues}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CollectionControlSelectedValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <RadioButtons .ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </RadioButtons .ItemTemplate>
</RadioButtons >
```

However, the only WPF RadioButton implementations I can find are **static** like this.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="rbHolder1" Style="{StaticResource rbStackPanelStyle}">
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource rbStyle}">RadioButton 1</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource rbStyle}">RadioButton 2</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource rbStyle}">RadioButton 3</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource rbStyle}">...</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

**How can I create a RadioButton control which is not static like the above but instead gets its data from its ItemsSource property as in the above ComboBox example?**

Answer (score 5):

Use ItemsControl and DataTemplate:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionControlValues}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding Value}" IsChecked="{Binding SomeProperty}" GroupName="name"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Don't you need to wrap the <DataTemplate> inside a <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>? At least the DataContext was still referring to the parent's DataContext instead of the item type.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1511516/134761

Comment: "Don't you need to wrap the <DataTemplate> inside a <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>?" Yup.

Answer (score 1):

code in window1.xaml file

```
<Window x="RadioButton.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:RadioButton"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="RadioOptions" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="local:RadioOption" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
        <Style x:Key="RadioButtonList" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">

            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />

            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />

            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">

                <Setter.Value>

                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >

                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />

                        <Setter Property="Template">

                            <Setter.Value>

                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">

                                    <Border Background="Transparent">

                                        <RadioButton Focusable="False"

                    IsHitTestVisible="False"

                    IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}">

                                            <ContentPresenter />

                                        </RadioButton>

                                    </Border>

                                </ControlTemplate>

                            </Setter.Value>

                        </Setter>

                    </Style>

                </Setter.Value>

            </Setter>

        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ListBox Margin="37,20,28,58" Name="listBox1" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RadioOptions}}"  />
</StackPanel>
```

this line

```
<ListBox` Margin="37,20,28,58" Name="listBox1" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RadioOptions}}"
```

is using itemsource property

C# code

```
namespace RadioButton
{
   public enum RadioOption
   {
    option1,
    option2,
    option3,
    option4
   }

public partial class Window1 : Window

{
    public Window1()

    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

}

}
```

i think this will help you out..

Comment: You should probably be using `ItemsControl` rather than `ListBox`, since the selection functionality of the latter isn't required.